# Is it possible to read the beginning of an S3 Inputstream more than once?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm currently getting a `ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>` from the `S3Client` (SDK 2), read it into a byte array and open two `ByteArrayInputStream` to pass them to Apache Tika and `ImageIO.read`.

Tika detectes the mimeType, `BufferedImage` is used to get height and width. Now both operations do not need to read the whole file (at least not for all image types). But reading into a byte array requires the consumption of the whole file.

Now how could I open two streams and just discard it when I'm done? Is the only way to perform two `getObject` calls to S3? `Mark` and `reset` isn't supported by the SDK.

Comment: Just read the whole stream into a byte[] and then create to ByteArrayInputStreams

Comment: That's what I currently do. But that's unnecessary memory consumption. Many times it's enough to read the beginning of the image to extract the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is while uploading the image, if you add the metadata info in the request, then you only need to call GetObjectMetadata method and you can get the information that you need without retrieving the whole object again.

```
s3Client.putObject(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, "Uploaded String Object");

            // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
            metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
```